# How to retrieve deleted files in Linux CentOS

Tags: linux, rm

I am using Fedora CentOS 6.2 and I accidentally removed all the files contained in a folder using command rm *. All the files were text files and none of the file was opened anywhere else or had .swp . Is there any way so that I can get them back . Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is really Linux-specific and not about Unix. It's actually file system-specific. Which file system are you using?

Comment: What's your filesystem type? The answer depends on it.

Comment: Use your backup. Otherwise, it depends upon your file system. Duplicate question of http://stackoverflow.com/q/9494653/841108

Comment: The file system in use is ext4.

Answer (score 5):

Get  your backups.If you don't have some, well  then you probably will keep some in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Use rmdir to remove "empty" directories in the future. It will refuse to remove a directory with something in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Testdisk or foremost to recover deleted files.